# Why is my setup module not being run in Magento 1.4.1.1?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I am creating a custom Magento module, and I cannot get the setup resource script to run. I am following Alan Storm's [tutorial](http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources) on it, but cannot seem to track down the issue.

I have scaled it down to simply attempt to force an error that my *...Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup cannot be found* as per the tutorial, but I cannot even seem to generate that (I get no errors at all).

The module does show up in System->Configuration->Advanced. I have all Magento caching disabled. There are no entries for this module in the core_resource table. What am I missing below? Shouldn't these two files be enough to generate an exception error such as:

```
Fatal error: Class 'CBTools_Twilliotool_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup' not found in
```

...since I do not have the class defined in Model/Resource/Mysql4/Setup.php? If so, then I am unfortunately not getting the error.

**app/etc/modules/CBTools_Twilliotool.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <CBTools_Twilliotool>
          <active>true</active>
           <codePool>local</codePool>
        </CBTools_Twilliotool>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/CBTools/Twilliotool/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <CBTools_Twilliotool>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </CBTools_Twilliotool>
    </modules>
    <models>
        <twilliotool>
            <class>CBTools_Twilliotool_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>twilliotool_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </twilliotool>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <twilliotool_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>CBTools_Twilliotool</module>
                <class>CBTools_Twilliotool_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </twilliotool_setup>
    </resources>
</config>
```

Comment: Without looking at things too deeply, are you running in developer mode?  Modern versions of Magento are better about swallowing exceptions for non existant classes.

Comment: Yes, I added had added to my index.php with no change:
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a configuration node.  The `<models>` and `<resource>` tags belong inside a `<global>` tag.

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <CBTools_Twilliotool>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </CBTools_Twilliotool>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <twilliotool>
                <class>CBTools_Twilliotool_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>twilliotool_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </twilliotool>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <twilliotool_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>CBTools_Twilliotool</module>
                    <class>CBTools_Twilliotool_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </twilliotool_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Alan, your were exactly correct. I missed that on the previous tutorial article. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need specific module installation logic like doing an action after applying all updates, just remove the `config/resources/twilliotool_setup/setup/class` node from config. In other way, create the `CBTools_Twilliotool_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup` class and extend it from `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup`